# I do not want to redirect users to my website when user installs my app from Bigcommerce App store..How could I do it?

Tags: bigcommerce

I had develop Bigcommerce APP. But right now when user install APP and launch it, its redirect to my website. I do not want to redirect to my website but working on same screen in Bigcommerce admin.

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: give more detail e.g. link to your app etc.

Answer (score 0):

The BigCommerce "Auth Callback Request" and "Load Callback Request", when fired, will hit a URL you specified with the Auth or Load content.  BigCommerce then expects a **200** status code response with an HTML response body.  The HTML that you supply back will be loaded into the iFrame of the Control Panel.  It is not clear from your question whether this is happening on the Auth or Load Callback but one of those two is involved.  Although, when you say, "...and launch it", that seems to imply you see this behavior on the "Load Callback Request".

If you are seeing the entire page redirect then the Auth or Load Callback URI you have supplied is probably returning a javascript that performs the redirect.  That or maybe your server is returning a **301** or **302** redirect instead of a **200** response.

Here is the documentation on the Auth Callback Request:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/callback

and the Load Callback Request:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/load